# Asignar la iteracion de un for de una objeto en una variable python

Tags: python, bucle-for

```
class Folios():

    #Metodo constructor de clase
    def __init__(self,numero,asunto,fecha,destinatario,remitente):
        self.numero = numero
        self. asunto = asunto
        self.fecha = fecha
        self. destinatario = destinatario
        self.remitente = remitente
        
lista = [
    Folios("001","Pago de Vacaciones","21/02/2020","Recursos Humanos","Innovacion"),
    Folios("002","Requisicion de Material","11/08/2020","Adquisiciones","Innovacion"),
    Folios("003","Entrega de Equipo de computo","17/09/2020","Ingresos","Innovacion")
]

def BuscarFolio(folio):
    for f in lista:
        if f.numero == folio:
            print("Folio: {} , asunto: {}, enviado ha: {} ".format(f.numero,f.asunto,f.destinatario))

**Como puedo asinar a una variable el objeto iterado atravez del return no solo imprimirlo....  **
```

BuscarFolio('003')

cuando mando a llamar la funcion BuscarFolio() recorro la lista  que tiene 3 objetos de la clase folio pero no deseo solo imprimirlos con el print, hay alguna manera de almacenar esa iteración del objeto, en este caso  '003' no se asignarlo a una variable return obj = f no se como hacerlo no tengo idea como

Comment: Exactamente qué es lo que quieres hacer? creo que deberías agregar más detalles a t pregunta

Comment: Solo cambia el print por un `return f ` ?

Comment: ya lo intente amigo pero no funciona..   def BuscarFolio(folio):
    
    for f in lista:
        if f.numero == folio:
            return " El asunto es.  {} ".format(f.asunto)

Comment: En lugar de `print(expresion_de_formato)` usa `return expresion_de_formato`

Answer (score 0):

Como te indica en los comentarios @Jhoubert Rincon necesitas poner un return, si además de imprimirlo quieres retornarlo. Sería así:

```
class Folios():

    #Metodo constructor de clase
    def __init__(self,numero,asunto,fecha,destinatario,remitente):
        self.numero = numero
        self. asunto = asunto
        self.fecha = fecha
        self. destinatario = destinatario
        self.remitente = remitente
        
lista = [
    Folios("001","Pago de Vacaciones","21/02/2020","Recursos Humanos","Innovacion"),
    Folios("002","Requisicion de Material","11/08/2020","Adquisiciones","Innovacion"),
    Folios("003","Entrega de Equipo de computo","17/09/2020","Ingresos","Innovacion")
]

def BuscarFolio(folio):
    for f in lista:
        if f.numero == folio:
            print("Folio: {} , asunto: {}, enviado ha {}".format(f.numero,f.asunto,f.destinatario))
            return f
```

De tal forma que ahora podrías guardar el objeto **f** en una variable y hacer lo que desees. Yo aquí simplemente extraigo el número y el asunto:

```
folio_003 = BuscarFolio("003")

print(folio_003.numero)
print(folio_003.asunto)
```

El output sería:

```
'003'
'Entrega de Equipo de computo'
```